# How to convert Excel to XML?

Tags: java, excel

I've a requirement something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174446/how-to-automate-converting-excel-xls-files-to-excel-xml-fromat). I've to convert an Excel to XML Spreadsheet. 
After googling, I found [jexcelApi](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/). But it's not retaining the format.

Any suggestions on ***How to convert an Excel to XML format, retaining the Excel formatting?***

Thanks :)

Comment: What version of Excel?  The 2007 (xlsx) is really a zip file, using xml as persistence.  There was a 2003 format (precursor to 2007) as well - Google OfficeML

Comment: Its Excel 2003. sorry, I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html)

Comment: Actually, I used POI only to generate the Excel file. My Java Web Service have to give the Excel in XML Spreadsheet to a .NET client. The .NET code will in turn convert the XML Spreadsheet to Excel and present it to user. I was not sure that POI can be used to convert Excel to XML UNTIL I saw this(http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2006/jw-1019-xmlexcel.html)!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you like this one too...it is not Open Source but matches your needs:
http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/01/09/q-and-a.html

Edit:
Comments on that Article are interessting too!

Answer (score 0):

For Reading an Excel file you need to use POI jars and for creating an XML you can use JDOM jar file (Jdom Parser to Parse XML).

Please find below link which has complete code of reading an Excel file and with that Excel file it is creating XML.

Link : https://github.com/monica11aug/ExploringThings/tree/main/ExcelToXmlConvertor