# Automate converting excel xls file to excel xml

Tags: php, mysql, file-conversion

I have a web page where a user can upload xls files. When he uploads a file, i want to automate converting the excel file to excel xml. I want to convert it to an xml file as i think it will be easy to handle the data. 
Is it possible to write my own php function to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand. You're going to read a XLS file, write it out as XLSX, then read in the XLSX?

Why not just [deal with the XLS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/) in the first place?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174446/how-to-automate-converting-excel-xls-files-to-excel-xml-fromat

I have found this code. Can the same thing be done in PHP?

Comment: I have to write a function of my own to read an excel file(.xls). There are several open source solutions to do that but I have to write my own file parser. Then I thought, why not try to convert the xls to an xml file which can be done by File-> Save as Excel Xml and then try to grab the data from the xml file which I can do. But in my application, the user will upload an excel file(.xls). That is why I want to automate converting an .xls file to .xml